# What algorithm does numpy random.normal uses? is it just the gaussian formula for normal distribution? does its use the mersenne twister?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, gaussian

I am a beginner and math algorithms are not my thing, but I was curious if the numpy random.normal uses the Mersenne twister or no because then it wouldn't be a normal distribution?

Comment: you can transform a uniform distribution into a  normal distribution (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling ). so you can use a mersenne twister to sample from a normal distribution. i don't know what numpy really uses.

Comment: that was helpful, thank you